# Variable line thickness for parts of the table

Tags: tables, line

I am using this code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}
\begin{document}
\newcolumntype{?}{!{\vrule width 1.5pt}}
\scalebox{1.1}{
\begin{tabular}{|c?c|c|c?c|}  \hline
    & & &  & \\   \specialrule{.13em}{.2em}{.2em} 
    $b_1$ &$a_1$ & $b_2$  &$a_2$& \\ \specialrule{.15em}{.2em}{.2em}
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

However, I just want the middle three cells in the second row to be enclosed by thicker lines, and everywhere else I need thinner lines. The output I get currently looks like this, and the thicker lines extend beyond the bottom three cells.

[image]

Comment: Welcome on TeX StackExchange! You should provide a complete MWE (*minimal working example*) with the `\documentclass`, `\begin{document}`, `\end{document}`, etc.

Comment: The `\specialrule` command is provided by the `booktabs` package. You should not use it in a context where you also use vertical lines. This is not really supported.

Answer (score 4):

With `{NiceTabular}` of `nicematrix`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nicematrix}

\begin{document}

\begin{NiceTabular}{ccccc}[hvlines]
\\
$b_1$ & \Block[draw,line-width=1pt,transparent]{1-3}{} 
        $a_1$ & $b_2$  & $a_2$ & \\ 
\\
\end{NiceTabular}

\end{document}
```

[image: Output of the above code]

Comment: I actually need to have eight of such tables, three each in the first couple of rows and two in the last row. When I try to input this code, where I already have used many other packages by default, it doesn't give this correct picture.

Comment: I have forgotten to say that, with `nicematrix`, you need several compilations.

Answer (score 2):

There are two problems in your code:

1. `\usepackage` should be used in the preamble, before `\begin{document}`.
2. `\specialrule` is a command provided by tbe `booktabs` package which you don't load in your example, so an error arises. Note that the `booktabs` package is not intended to be used for tabular material with vertical rules, but you can set the vertical spacing of the `\specialrule` command to zero by setting the second and third argument to `0pt`.

So, you could do the following:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array, booktabs}
\newcolumntype{?}{!{\vrule width 1.5pt}}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{ | c ? c | c | c ? c |}
\hline
      &       &       &       & \\ \specialrule{.13em}{0pt}{0pt}
$b_1$ & $a_1$ & $b_2$ & $a_2$ & \\ \specialrule{.13em}{0pt}{0pt}
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image]

---

But for what you actually want, a modern and more flexible approach would be to use the `tabularray` package:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\begin{document}
\begin{tblr}{
    colspec={ c c c c c },
    hlines,
    vlines,
    hline{2,3}={2-4}{2pt},
    vline{2,5}={2-4}{2pt}
}
      &       &       &       & \\ 
$b_1$ & $a_1$ & $b_2$ & $a_2$ & \\ 
\end{tblr}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer. And yes, that was an oversight, I put the \usepackage before \begin{document}. However, I only want the thick lines enclosing the middle three cells of the bottom row, whereas I mistakenly only could get them to extend beyond the three cells.

Comment: Thank you for the update!

Comment: Somehow this is not working in a latex template where, by default I also use a ton of other packages; the tabularray package is not loading.

Comment: Do you get any error in your log? Does the other solution with `NiceTabular` work for you? You should probably show your log so that we can identify package incompatibilities.